# Make a list into a dictionary, indexed by a label in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a csv file containing peoples' details, such as:

```
1010,Bill,145.98
1147,Gina,10288.97
2917, Willie, 4.97
```

and I want to create a dictionary called `entries` so that `entries["Gina"]` would return the sublist `[1147,'Gina',10288.97]`. My attempt so far

```
with open('namesFile.txt', 'r') as f:
    entries = {}
    people = f.readlines()
    people = [person.strip().split(',') for person in people]
    print(people)
    for person in range(len(people)):
        entries[person] = person[1]
```

gives me a `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` error. It produces a nice nested list of people:

```
[['1010', 'Bill', '145.98'], ['1147', 'Gina', '10288.97'], ['2917', ' Willie', ' 4.97']]
```

and I'm not sure how to organise the dictionary based on the person's name (`person[1]` in the code), which is the intended purpose of the last two lines of code.

How can I put the entries into a dictionary in this fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
entries = {}
with open('namesFile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        x, name, y = line.split(',')
        name = name.strip()
        entries[name] = [int(x), name, float(y)]
```

Using `csv` module provides some versatility as it is easier to adapt to various formats:

```
import csv
entries = {}
with open('namesFile.txt') as f:
    for x, name, y in csv.reader(f):
        name = name.strip()
        entries[name] = [int(x), name, float(y)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('namesFile.txt', 'r') as f:
    entries = {}
    people = f.readlines()
    people = [person.strip().split(',') for person in people]
    print(people)
    for person in people:
        entries[person] = person[1]
```

The error is on the sixth line. Using `range(len(people))` will make `person` the *index* of the nested list you're iterating, not the nested list itself.

**EDIT:** read chrisz's comment. I agree, the third and fourth lines could potentially take a long time. Use `readline` instead to read line by line, and write to the dictionary one line at a time (instead of all at once from the list `people`).

Comment: I would say better to iterate line by line here, in case the file is very large.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `csv` module to read the file and iterate over records in order to create the dictionary as follows:

```
import csv

entries = {}
with open('namesFile.txt', 'r') as infile:
    rows = csv.reader(infile)

    for row in rows:
        name = row[1]
        entries[name] = row

print('entries', entries)
```

output :

```
{' Willie': ['2917', ' Willie', ' 4.97'], 'Bill': ['1010', 'Bill', '145.98'], 'Gina': ['1147', 'Gina', '10288.97']}
```

Is that what you want? Let me know if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using a 3rd party library, you can use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

# read file
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=',', header=None, columns=['x', 'name', 'y'])

# remove whitespace from names
df['name'] = df['name'].str.strip()

# set index to name
df.index = df['name']

# output to file
res.to_csv('file_out.csv', index=False)

# create dictionary from dataframe
res = df.to_dict(orient='index')

print(res)

{'Bill': {'name': 'Bill', 'x': 1010, 'y': 145.98},
 'Gina': {'name': 'Gina', 'x': 1147, 'y': 10288.97},
 'Willie': {'name': 'Willie', 'x': 2917, 'y': 4.97}}
```

By a minor change, you can output a key to list mapping instead of key to `dict`.